# Discord.py and SQL: Not all members are being added to the database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

When i run this command/query not everyone is being added into the database, only a few members are. I tried seeing if the "status" of the member mattered but that is not the case

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Ready")
    guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_NUM)
    print(f"{guild}")
    memberList = guild.members
    print(memberList)
    for m in memberList:
        c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO dodos 
                VALUES ('{m.id}',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                """)
        conn.commit()

        print(f"Adding {m} into database as {m.id}")
        c.execute(f"""SELECT *
                        FROM dodos
                        WHERE id = {m.id}
        """)
        conn.commit()
        print(c.fetchall())
```

[image: Example output]

Code:

Comment: What's the difference between `c` and `conn` here? You are committing `conn` only

Comment: conn is my sqlite3 connection and c is conn.cursor()

Comment: It may be worth cleaning this up with SQLAlchemy and using an object to represent your table. Then you can do `conn.add(...)` instead of raw SQL statements. That may end up resolving your issue, but if not try querying outside of the loop execution and see if the inserts work

Comment: Looks like rounding is the issue, just tried those numbers and they get modified when they're added into the database. Any tips on how to avoid this/should i change the database column type into a TEXT instead

Comment: It's best to store ID's as strings and then convert them to int when passing them to Discord.py

Comment: You should not be adding all the members. use `on_message` and `on_member_join` to add them. This means you use less storage for self bots or people who forgot about discord.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: REAL/INTEGER didn't work as the type for m.id as it rounded due to not having enough space so saving them as TEXT fixed the issue